# Formula error while counting unique entries in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

```
       200    Pass
ABC    201    Pass    
       202    fail    

       300    Pass
DEF    201    Pass
       202    Fail
```

I have a table which looks like the one shown above. The cells on the left are merged (i.e. ABC is one merged cell and DEF is another). I want to count the number of unique entries in the second column.

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(C4:C4700)>0,MATCH(C4:C4700,C4:C4700,0),""), 
        IF(LEN(C4:C4700)>0,MATCH(C4:C4700,C4:C4700,0),""))>0,
        1))
```

When the above formula is used to count the number of unique entries, there is an error.
When calculation steps were followed, I found that Excel was not able to calculate `LEN(C4:C4700)`.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Please pay attention to formatting. Your question was barely legible. I've corrected it for you this time.

Answer (score 1):

this should help you

`=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B4700<>"")/COUNTIF(B1:B4700,B1:B4700&""))`

Comment: How does it work?